# How to reverse the direction of scroll with Wacom Touch on Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, debian, touch

I have a Wacom Touch and using it with Debian. It works fine except the the double finger scrolling is the reverse of what I prefer. Is there a way to change the direction of the Wacom Touch two finger scroll on Debian?

As far as I know there is no gui app for Wacom on Linux so I used xsetwacom to query some variables associated with the device however I did not spot anything I am able to use.

thanks

Comment: Using `xmodmap` to swap buttons 4 and 5 doesn't work?

Comment: That is not the issue. Issue is scrolling up and down not the buttons even if I do that through swapping it wil then swap my touchpads direction

Comment: @yaruncan Has the problem been resolved for you? Otherwise, this question keeps getting promoted to the home page in the hope that you will accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a Mac go into system preferences, click on the Warcom Tablet icon at the bottom of the screen. Under tool - press Touch, change scroll to "standard"

Comment: Does changing this setting to standard reverse it then?

Answer (score 0):

The linuxwacom issue tracker has an open request to add this feature: https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/issues/28. As per the issue, a temporary workaround is to add a configuration file that causes the Wacom touchpad to be handled by the xf86-input-libinput driver instead. Afterwards, you should be able to configure the scroll direction in the same way as any other touchpad (e.g. through the GNOME Control Center, or with the `Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"` xorg.conf.d option)